# MySQL UNION: How to get data in two columns

Tags: mysql, union

I have this SQL:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as "With Gold"  FROM user_accounts_gold WHERE level = 6
UNION
SELECT COUNT(*) as "No Gold"    FROM user_accounts_bronze WHERE level = 6
```

At the moment this outputs:

```
| With Gold |
-------------
| 17734     |
| 2388      |
```

Is there a way to get this to output like so:

```
| With Gold | No Gold |
----------------------
| 17734     | 2388    |
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have different tables for gold and bronze accounts?

Comment: Not me, a client.

Answer (score 10):

Do a `CROSS JOIN` instead:

```
select * from
(SELECT COUNT(*) as "With Gold"  FROM user_accounts_gold WHERE level = 6) ug
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT COUNT(*) as "No Gold"    FROM user_accounts_bronze WHERE level = 6) ub
```

Comment: I can confirm that it's working very well for my case, many thanks @jarlh!

Answer (score 3):

Another way you can do it in `select` subquery

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) as "With Gold"  FROM user_accounts_gold WHERE level = 6),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) as "No Gold"    FROM user_accounts_bronze WHERE level = 6)
```

**Oracle**

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) as "With Gold"  FROM user_accounts_gold WHERE level = 6),
       (SELECT COUNT(*) as "No Gold"    FROM user_accounts_bronze WHERE level = 6)
FROM dual
```

or you can do it by *condition aggregate function*

```
SELECT MAX(CASE WHEN  grp = 'With Gold' then val END) as 'With Gold',
       MAX(CASE WHEN  grp = 'No Gold' then val END) as 'No Gold'
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*)  val,'With Gold' grp  FROM user_accounts_gold WHERE level = 6
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*)  ,'No Gold'    FROM user_accounts_bronze WHERE level = 6
)t
GROUP BY grp
```

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, there should only be one table. So create a view for it. On-the-fly, if you want. Then count:

```
select
  sum(metal = 'gold') as "With Gold",
  sum(metal <> 'gold') as "No Gold"
from
(
  select 'gold' as metal, level from user_accounts_gold
  union all
  select 'bronze' as metal, level from user_accounts_bronze
) one_table
where level = 6;
```

With a persistent view (i.e. `CREATE VIEW ...`) this would boil down to:

```
select
  sum(metal = 'gold') as "With Gold",
  sum(metal <> 'gold') as "No Gold"
from one_table
where level = 6;
```

and you could benefit from the view in other queries, too.

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT 
COUNT(a.level) AS 'With Gold', 
COUNT(b.level) as 'No Gold'
FROM user_accounts_gold a, user_accounts_bronze b`

Comment: if he added the WHERE clause for Level checking, it could be done. I just forgot the WHERE clause to filter level values with 6

Comment: Will still not return the correct values... E.g. if there are 4 gold values and 5 bronze values, this query will return (20, 20).

Comment: On a sidenote: Comma-separated joins were made redundat in 1992. If you want a cross join then say `CROSS JOIN`. Standard delimiters for names are the double quotes. Using single quotes instead, which are string literal delimiters according to the SQL standard, is prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT SUM("With Gold") AS "With Gold", SUM("No Gold") AS "No Gold" 
    FROM
    (
     SELECT COUNT(*) as "With Gold", 0 AS "No Gold"  FROM user_accounts_gold WHERE level = 6
     UNION
     SELECT  0 AS "With Gold", COUNT(*) as "No Gold"    FROM user_accounts_bronze WHERE level = 6
    )
```